# System.__ComObject does not contain a method named 'Range'

Tags: excel, powershell

Powershell with excel novice here.  I'm learning how to interact with excel via powershell and discovered a 'range' feature on several sites.

Strange thing is, this feature does not work on my system and returns the following error: `Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Range'.`

Can anyone help me with having my powershell use the range feature?

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $false
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open(“c:\test.csv")
$Workbook.Range("A:Z").Find('05/**/**')
```

Comment: Range is a property of a Worksheet object, not a Workbook.  So not that strange ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`Find`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find.aspx) is a member of [**`Range`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find.aspx), but `Range` is not a member of the [**`Workbook`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook_members.aspx) object. It is a property of [**`Worksheet`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301176.aspx).

I recommend you check out the documentation, especially as you may need to use `FindNext` and `FindPrevious`.

```
$Workbook  = $xl.workbooks.open(“c:\test.csv")
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Workbook.Range("A:Z").Find('05/**/**')
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  any links to documentation would be very appreciated

Comment: My bad, didn't realize those were links.  Thank you very much